# PHP true false statement with expection

Tags: php, if-statement

i have some code that im editing for an auction website, the thing is that i need the $all_unpaid = false if the bid_amount is zero, I tried several tweaks but no results, perhaps some1 can have some suggestions?

```
function direct_payment_multiple ($invoice_id, $items_array, $dp_array, $buyer_id)
{
    $output = false;

    $nb_sub_arrays = count($dp_array);
    if ($nb_sub_arrays)
    {
        $array_result = $dp_array[0];

        for ($i=1; $i<$nb_sub_arrays; $i++)
        {
            $array_result = @array_intersect($array_result, $dp_array[$i]);
        }

        $all_unpaid = true;
        for ($i=0; $i<$nb_sub_arrays; $i++)
        {
            $all_unpaid = (!$items_array[$i]['direct_payment_paid'] && !$items_array[$i]['flag_paid'] && $items_array[$i]['bid_amount'] > 0) ? $all_unpaid : false;
        }

        $same_currency = true;
        $currency = $items_array[0]['currency'];
        for ($i=0; $i<$nb_sub_arrays; $i++)
        {
            $same_currency = ($currency == $items_array[$i]['currency']) ? $same_currency : false;
        }
    }

    $output = (is_array($array_result) && $all_unpaid) ? true : false;

    return $output;
}
```

some overview, this auction website allows users to place a bid of 0.00, if no-one outbids them then they get the item for free, however if someone does outbid them then regular code applies

hey @TecBrat, i deleted this line

```
$all_unpaid = (!$items_array[$i]['direct_payment_paid'] && !$items_array[$i]['flag_paid'] && $items_array[$i]['bid_amount'] > 0) ? $all_unpaid : false;
```

and replaced it with this

```
$all_unpaid =true;
if ((!$items_array[$i]['direct_payment_paid'] && !$items_array[$i]['flag_paid'] )
    || !$items_array[$i]['bid_amount'] > 0)
  {
    $all_unpaid =false;
  }
```

however it seems to do the same as b4

i changed it to this

```
                $all_unpaid =true;
if (($items_array[$i]['direct_payment_paid'] || $items_array[$i]['flag_paid'] )
    || $items_array[$i]['bid_amount'] > 0)
  {
    $all_unpaid =false;
  }
```

still appears to be the same as b4

currently this is what im working with

```
    function direct_payment_multiple ($invoice_id, $items_array, $dp_array, $buyer_id)
    {
        $output = false;

        $nb_sub_arrays = count($dp_array);
        if ($nb_sub_arrays)
        {
            $array_result = $dp_array[0];

            for ($i=1; $i<$nb_sub_arrays; $i++)
            {
                $array_result = @array_intersect($array_result, $dp_array[$i]);
            }

            $all_unpaid = true;
            for ($i=0; $i<$nb_sub_arrays; $i++)
            {
$all_unpaid =true; if (($items_array[$i]['direct_payment_paid'] || $items_array[$i]['flag_paid'] ) || $items_array[$i]['bid_amount'] > 0)

  {
    $all_unpaid =false;

  }
            }

            $same_currency = true;
            $currency = $items_array[0]['currency'];
            for ($i=0; $i<$nb_sub_arrays; $i++)
            {
                $same_currency = ($currency == $items_array[$i]['currency']) ? $same_currency : false;
            }
        }

        $output = (is_array($array_result) && $all_unpaid) ? true : false;

        return $output;
    }
```

Comment: the problem is if payment has been made and is greater then zero then all_unpaid is true, if payment equal to zero or there is no payment then all_unpaid is false,

Comment: @TecBrat  i edited as you suggested, same results as b4

Comment: @TecBrat where should i put the echo commands to see them?

Comment: I removed my answer and comments so that someone else will see that you have not received the help you need. I really was trying to help but I don't think I'm helping you much.

Comment: I undeleted my answer and added a tested solution. Please see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line:

```
$all_unpaid = (!$items_array[$i]['direct_payment_paid'] && !$items_array[$i]['flag_paid'] && $items_array[$i]['bid_amount'] > 0) ? $all_unpaid : false;
```

is a good example of why I prefer this style:

```
if(condition){do stuff}
```

I think I translated that correctly as

```
if (!$items_array[$i]['direct_payment_paid'] 
    && !$items_array[$i]['flag_paid'] 
    && $items_array[$i]['bid_amount'] > 0)
  {
    $all_unpaid =$all_unpaid;
  }
else
  {
    $all_unpaid = false
  }
```

...

I tested this script at http://www.tecbrat.com/conditional_testing.php

```
<?php

$items_array['direct_payment_paid']=(int)$_GET['direct_payment_paid'];
$items_array['flag_paid']=(int)$_GET['flag_paid'];
$items_array['bid_amount']=$_GET['bid_amount'];

// simplified from //function direct_payment_multiple ($invoice_id, $items_array, $dp_array, $buyer_id)    
function direct_payment_multiple_tester ($items_array)
  {
    $all_unpaid =true;
    if ($items_array['direct_payment_paid'] || $items_array['flag_paid']
        || !$items_array['bid_amount'] > 0)
      {
        $all_unpaid =false;
      }
    return $all_unpaid;
  }

if (direct_payment_multiple_tester ($items_array))
  {
    echo "we still need payment";
  }
 else
  {
    echo "We received payment, or there is no charge.";
  }

echo '<pre>';
print_r($items_array);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Try it with a few different query strings to see what happens.

http://www.tecbrat.com/conditional_testing.php?direct_payment_paid=1&flag_paid=0&bid_amount=50

http://www.tecbrat.com/conditional_testing.php?direct_payment_paid=0&flag_paid=1&bid_amount=50

http://www.tecbrat.com/conditional_testing.php?direct_payment_paid=1&flag_paid=1&bid_amount=50

http://www.tecbrat.com/conditional_testing.php?direct_payment_paid=0&flag_paid=0&bid_amount=0

http://www.tecbrat.com/conditional_testing.php?direct_payment_paid=0&flag_paid=0&bid_amount=50

Comment: i do not comprehend what you mean by "that style"?? What I am trying to do is have $all_unpaid=  = false if the bid_amount happens to be zero but if bid_amount is greater then zero then $all_unpaid = true

Comment: @FrankLy "that style" is very hard to read, debug and maintain

Comment: testing ^^ will let you know in a few minutes, thanks for your help !!

Comment: @TecBrat echoing $i, will let you know in a few

Comment: hmm, i can't find the echoed values, where should i put the echo generally?

Comment: @FrankLy I think you'll need to better understand the programming language you're using before anyone's answers will help you.

Comment: @TecBrat i dont know why i waited so long for your answer only to have you insult me

Comment: @FrankLy, I am not attempting to insult you. We were all new @ some point, & we all have room to improve. (That's the whole reason we come to this site.) My previous comment was in response to comments from you that indicate either your knowledge & experience has not yet prepared you for this project, or you just aren't really trying very hard. I hope it's knowledge & experience. Do you know how `echo` works? Start putting `echo` commands to show progress so you know what blocks of code are executing. `echo` important variables to see what values are being assigned. Troubleshoot from there.

Comment: i can check the values in the database and its not that, yes i know what the echo and print_f function does, its something in the $array_result because i tried putting >0 to == 2 and that is obvs false, yet it is still showing up as true

Comment: @TecBrat hey i managed to just use a sql update query to forcefully change it so the problem is solved :) thanks for your time involved!